# What are the differences between the Optical Carrier (OC) and Synchronous Transport Mode (STM) protocols, in regards to SONET/SDH?

Tags: layer1

I understand that OC-3c and STM-1 are technically consistent, and STM-1 can transport different quantities of CEPT-N signals, but why not just use OC-3c and forget STM altogether?

Edit:
Originally mistaken OC-3 for OC-3c.

Comment: OC3 and STM-1 are _not_ equivalent. STM-1 is equivalent of OC-3c that concatenates three STS-1. The details of the frames are different.

Comment: By the way, those are not transport (OSI layer-4) protocols, they are physical/data-link (OSI layer-1/2) protocols.

Comment: @RonMaupin Sorry, this was using the language of the author who wrote a textbook in the 80's, but yes they are physical/data-link protocols. I'll make an edit.

Comment: @RonMaupin In response to your first comment, why have an STM-1 if it's equivalent to an OC-3c?

Comment: STM-1 came first. OC3c was in response. You have to understand that you are dealing with multiple standards bodies, and there is always the "_not invented here_" syndrome. SONET is a North American standard, but SDH is used in most of the rest of the world. As things have progressed, the standards have come closer to help interoperability. You do not just rip and replace a huge capital investment in hardware supporting one protocol when a new on comes out in another part of the world.

Comment: @RonMaupin I see. I think my confusion branched from the wrong idea that SONET and SDH signals didn't require any conversion form one to the other. Thank you for clearing that up.